# What is the best data type to store list of email Ids in database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, email, sqldatatypes

My requirement is to store a list of emailIds in a single column, What would be the best **data type** to do so? My columns are like EmailTo , EmailCC, EmailBCC in which I would require storing the list of Ids. Also , help me with the *size* of the datatype.
I am using SQL server.

Comment: Bad idea. Was the requirement to store the data like this or being able to display it like this?

Comment: The Requirement is to store the data. It is for the configuration purse while sending e-mail. (Using C#).

Comment: The requierment should be changed. There is a cost for bad designs.

Comment: What could be the best suggestion then?

Comment: Record for each email, including email type. When you retrieve the data, you concatenate it using `XML path ('')` or other technic

Answer (score 5):

It's good to go with `NVARCHAR(320)` - 64 characters for local part + @ + 255 for domain name.

You can refer [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86323/standard-data-types-for-email-address-telephone-number-first-name-rixh-text) for more information.

Comment: Good reference. Aaron Bertrand is a SQL Server MVP. His work is known throughout the community.

Comment: A reference for what? Was Aaron talking about storing a list in a single column?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz He did not, and neither did Jibin.

Comment: @TT.,you don't want to be disingenuous. Jibin responded directly to Kalyani's request "help me with the size of the datatype." . Every time an OP starts with "I have a list stored in a single column" everybody starts throwing ricochets at him/her like he/she was the database architect, but when we finally have the opportunity to impact a design in progress and give a real value to the OP, suddenly everybody become quiet.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I'm not being disingenuous neither did I intend to be. Jibin's answer is only referring to storing a single address in a single column. He's explicitely stating how he comes up with the length based on analysis by Aaron Bertrand, and that for a single address. IMO Jibin is not encouraging bad design with his answer. He may be answering to a different question (what data type for a single address) though, I'll grant you that.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz I think you took it too far in going around the page telling your downvoting. It would have been more constructive to write your answer explaining your solution: (1) why it's a bad idea to store all emailIds in a single column/record (although it should be clear, it won't hurt the beginners to understand and you to prove you know what you talk about), (2) a proposed design, pretty much as this answer does. It might have been enough to suggest an edit, as the OP is ambiguous: is the list of email ids to be stored in a single record or a "single column" over multiple records?

Answer (score -1):

For email , please use data type as **VARCHAR[(n)]**

According to defination in **MSSQL Server 2008**

**VARCHAR[(n)]** : Describes a variable-length string of single- byte characters.In contrast to the CHAR data type, the values for the VARCHAR data type are stored in their actual length. This data type has two synonyms: **CHAR VARYING** and **CHARACTER VARYING**

---

In building database , I used VARCHAR(45) ,this was working fine for email purposes.

Comment: only use `VARCHAR` (over `NVARCHAR`) if you never have to cope with internationalised domain names

Answer (score -1):

The best data type to store a list (any kind of a list, not just e-mail IDs) is a table. Simple table.

For example, if it is a list of integers, the table would have an `int` column.

This is what RDBMS is for - they are designed to store data in a bunch of tables.

---

In your case you'd have several tables: `EmailsTo`, `EmailsCC`, `EmailsBCC`. The structure of your tables would depend on what your `EmailID` is, what type it is and what other related information (columns) you may need.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz, re: (2). Why not? There are many ways to model it. "To", "CC", "BCC" are standard fields and I don't think any new similar fields would be introduced. So, it is fine to put these three types as separate tables. It is also fine to put all of them into one table with a "type" column. There is not enough information in the question to make this decision. Just don't try to put a "list" into a `varchar` column.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz, Actually, it all depends on the intended use of the data. If you need to store a text representation of the BCC field and never intend to do any analysis/querying/processing of this text, just store it as-is and retrieve it to stick into e-mail client, then simple `nvarchar(max)` is also adequate. If you need to do a lot of searches among the "To" recipients and rarely among the "BCC" recipients, it makes sense to separate them. This question has too little details and can't be answered. I should have ignored it, but got caught by the word "list".

Comment: Would you store a data in a form that does not enable you to  analysis/querying/processing, ever?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz, of course, yes. There are cases when storing a blob of text in `nvarchar(max)` is a good idea. When you need just a dumb storage of a text "as-is". When you don't intend to split this text into sub-components within the SQL queries. That's what `nvarchar(max)` and `varbinary(max)` are for.

Comment: I wouldn't expect you to manipulate an image within the database, or a PDF document, or even a textual format of a book, but this was not what you were talking about - "If you need to store a text representation of the BCC field and never intend to do any...".

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz, actually, that's exactly what I was talking about. There are cases when you should store BCC field as a blob of `nvarchar(max)`. And there are cases when you'd better normalize it further and store it as a separate table with one recipient per row. This question doesn't provide enough details that would allow to choose either variant. Ideally, it should not be answered until it is clarified.

Answer (score -2):

Seems Datatype Issue to me.To answer your question ,in my view *VARCHAR(MAX)* is the highest that can store up-to 8k characters or may be even more if you cast it, but that would not be  the correct approach to do.
What you can do is to create a *COMMON GROUP* and enlist all the email id's to whom you want to send emails. This wont even occupy much of your Datatype space and all peoples can be included within that group as per your comments since you told you require it for sending emails to people.

Comment: Another downvote for dealing with technicalities instead of bad design for development on progress

Comment: ...also `VARCHAR(MAX)` can go greater than 8Kb